# Setting PHP Mime Type?

Tags: php, perl, mime

I am trying to work hands-on with web servers and such, so I decided I would see what I can do with an old perl web server. I need to serve php files with httpd-php and not just plain text, after doing some digging around on google I found that "application/x-httpd-php" should do the trick, but it isn't..

```
jpg image/jpeg
html    text/html
htm text/html
pdf application/pdf
gif image/gif
pl  text/plain
sh  text/plain
txt text/plain
mpeg    video/mpeg
pas text/plain
php     application/x-httpd-php
```

how do I tell mime to serve php files WITH PHP?

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

#
# $Header: /export/cvs/www.ogris.de/httpd/httpd.pl_,v 1.2 2002/11/10 22:55:45 fjo Exp $
#

use IO::Socket;

$PROGRAM_NAME = "Simple-HTTP";
$PIDFILE = "$PROGRAM_NAME.pid";
$TIMEZONE = "+0200";
%HTTPCODE = (
  200 => "Ok",
  404 => "Not found"
);
@MONTH = (Jan,Feb,Mar,Apr,May,Jun,Jul,Aug,Sep,Oct,Nov,Dec);
$PORT = 8001;
$DEFAULT_MIME = "text/plain";
$MIME = $ARGV[0] or $MIME = "mime.txt";

$SIG{TERM} = \&cleanup;
$SIG{KILL} = \&cleanup;
$SIG{INT}  = \&cleanup;
$SIG{HUP}  = sub { &load_mime("reloading mime types...") };
$SIG{CHLD} = sub { wait };

if (open(FH,"$PIDFILE")) {
  $pid = <FH>;
  close(FH);
  if (kill 0,$pid) {
    &error("$PROGRAM_NAME already running (pid=$pid)");
  }
  else {
    &warning("removing old pid file");
  }
}
if (open(FH,">$PIDFILE")) {
  print FH $$;
  close(FH);
}
else {
  &warning("can not write pid file $PIDFILE: $!");
}

&load_mime();

$listen = IO::Socket::INET->new(LocalPort=>$PORT, ReuseAddr=>1, Proto=>'tcp',
                                Listen=>1024) ||
  &error("can not create socket: $!");

&warning("$PROGRAM_NAME starting...");
while (my $socket = $listen->accept()) {
  $pid = fork();
  if ($pid == 0) {
    while ((my $s = <$socket>) ne "\r\n") {
      if ($s =~ /^get ([^\s]*)/io) {
        $url = $1;
        ($request = $s) =~ s/\r|\n//go;
      }
    }
    (my $file = ".$url") =~ s/\.\.//go;
    if (-d $file) {
      $file .= "/" if $file !~ /\/$/o;
      $mime = "html";
      if (($content = &read_file($file."index.html")) ne "") {
        $code = 200;
      }
      elsif (!opendir(DH,$file)) {
        $code = 404;
        $content = &http_error($socket,$code,$url);
      }
      else {
        @dir = readdir(DH);
        closedir(DH);
        $code = 200;
        $content = "<html><head><title>Index of $url</title></head><body>";
        $content.= "<h1>Index of $url</h1><pre><table>";
        foreach (sort @dir) {
          $content .= "<tr><td><a href=\"$_";
          if (-d "$file$_") {
            $content .= "/\">$_/</a></td><td align=right>-";
          }
          else {
            my $size = -s "$file$_";
            $content .= "\">$_</a></td><td align=right>";
            $content .= &sizef($size);
          }
          $content .= "</td></tr>";
        }
        $content.= "</pre></table>".&address($socket);
      }
    }
    elsif (($content = &read_file($file)) ne "") {
      $code = 200;
      $mime = substr($file,rindex($file,'.')+1);
    }
    else {
      $code = 404;
      $mime = "html";
      $content = &http_error($socket,$code,$url);
    }
    my $len = length($content);
    print $socket &http_out($code,$mime,$len,$content);
    print &common_log($socket,$request,$code,$len);
    $socket->close();
    &byebye();
  }
}

sub read_file
{
 my $file = shift;
 if ( (-f $file) && (open(FH,$file)) ) {
   binmode FH;
   while (<FH>) { $content .= $_; }
   close(FH);
   binmode $socket;
   return $content;
 }
 else {
   return "";
 }
}

sub http_error
{
  my $socket = shift;
  my $code = shift;
  my $url = shift;

  my $ret = "<html><head><title>$code $HTTPCODE{$code}</title></head><body>";
  $ret .= "<h1>$HTTPCODE{$code}</h1><p>The requested URL $url was not found on";
  $ret .= " this server.</p>".&address($socket);
  return $ret;
}

sub address
{
  my $socket = shift;
  my $server = $socket->sockhost();
  my $port = $socket->sockport();

  my $ret =  "<hr><address>Simple HTTP on $server:$port <br>";
  $ret .= scalar localtime(time)."</address></body></html>";
  return $ret;
}

sub http_out
{
  my $code = shift;
  my $mime = shift;
  my $len = shift;
  my $content = shift;
  my $ret = "HTTP/0.9 $code $HTTPCODE{$code}\r\nContent-type: ";
  $ret .= &get_mime($mime)."\r\nContent-length: ".$len."\r\n";
  $ret .= "Connection: close\r\n\r\n$content";
}

sub common_log
{
  my $socket = shift;
  my $request = shift;
  my $code = shift;
  my $len = shift;

  my $jetzt = time();
  my $remotehost = $socket->peerhost();

  my $ret = "$remotehost - - [".&datetimestamp($jetzt);
  $ret .= "] \"$request\" $code $len\n";
}

sub datetimestamp
{
  my $jetzt = shift;
  my ($sec,$min,$hour,$day,$mon,$year,@rest) = localtime($jetzt);
  $year += 1900;
  foreach ($sec,$min,$hour,$day) {
    $_ = "0$_" if $_ < 10;
  }
  return "$day/$MONTH[$mon]/$year:$hour:$min:$sec $TIMEZONE";
}

sub cleanup
{
  if (!unlink $PIDFILE) {
    &warning("can not remove pid file $PIDFILE: $!");
  }
  &warning("$PROGRAM_NAME shutting down...");
  &byebye();
}

sub load_mime
{
  %MIME = ();
  if (open(MFH,$MIME)) {
    &warning($_[0]) if $_[0];
    my @inhalt = <MFH>;
    close (MFH);
    %MIME = map {
      s/\r|\n//go;
      my @split = split(/\t/,$_);
      $split[0] => $split[1]
    } @inhalt;
  }
  else {
    &warning("can not read $MIME: $!");
  }
}

sub get_mime
{
  my $ret = $MIME{$_[0]};
  $ret = $DEFAULT_MIME if $ret eq "";
  return $ret;
}

sub error
{
  &warning($_[0]);
  &byebye();
}

sub warning
{
  print STDERR "[".&datetimestamp(time)."] $_[0]\n";
}

sub sizef
{
  my $size = shift;
  my $i = 0;
  my @SIZES = ("","k","M","G","T");
  while ($size > 1024) {
    $size /= 1024;
    $i++;
  }
  return sprintf("%.0f",$size).$SIZES[$i];
}

sub byebye
{
  close (STDERR);
  close (STDOUT);
  exit;
}
```

from http://www.ogris.de/httpd/

Answer (score 0):

> how do I tell mime to serve php files WITH PHP?

The `PHP` should be served as a [CGI script](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Gateway_Interface), which your web server apparently doesn't support.

(For simplicity sake, I'm omitting all security considerations.)

Crudely explained, a page which is a CGI script, instead of been send to the client verbatim, is executed by HTTP server as an application, and its output is sent to the client.

To implement the CGI script support in its simplest form, you would need:

1. Add configuration table of MIME types which are CGI scripts.
2. Before sending the file to the client, check if the MIME type corresponds to the CGI. If it does, and the file is executable, then run it, and pipe the `stdout` to the client socket.

To test that, you can add a MIME type for the (canonical extension) `.cgi` files, and create simple shell or Perl script (with extension `.cgi`) which should:

- print the HTTP header (separated by `"\n\r"`) including the (most important) `Content-Type` field.
- print extra `"\n\r\n\r"` as a separator between header and the content,
- print the content (e.g. simply print "Hello World").

In a full-fledged CGI implementation, the server passes extra information to the CGI script via [the environment variables](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Gateway_Interface#Syntax). Web server also needs to read and process the HTTP header generated by the CGI script, to extend it with the additional [HTTP field](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields) or to simply check that the header is valid. If scripts couldn't be started or produced empty output or terminated with an error, use the HTTP status code 500 to report the problem to the client.

Now to the PHP. Most PHP pages are not designed as CGI, since PHP most of the time is configured to be loaded by the web server as a shared library (or as the [FastCGI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FastCGI)). Thus, even if you implement full proper CGI interface, most `.php` files would still fail to work. You would have to extend the CGI support with your own "integration" for the PHP. The simplest way [to execute a PHP file](http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.options.php) is to run it with the `php -f <file.php>`. In other words, you need to add to your web server additional configuration, telling that some CGI MIME types shouldn't be run directly, but instead executed with the help of external process.

P.S. Other web server implementations you can check:

- http://utopia.knoware.nl/~hlub/uck/rlwrap/#p5httpd
- http://sourceforge.net/projects/lwpwserver/
- http://www.floodgap.com/httpi/